# Ethereum network on Azure geth error

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, microsoft-azure

I had some problems with my node in the ethereum network in azure and I restarted it (too many pending transactions)

When I logged back into the node, I saw that geth wasn't running (no logs, `ps auwxx` did not show geth and `geth attach` failed as well).

I can see that there is a file start-private-blockchain.sh but I can't seem to run it (permission denied, even when I do sudo).

I could potentially run geth manually by just typing in geth and some configs but is there a better way of doing this? should azure have had restarted geth as well when I restarted the node?

Comment: automatically starting a process on system start is a question which is not concerned with gerh. in this sense, you can ask it at SO, or more suitably at superuser.com,  geth is just like another process, and can be scheduled to start on system start like other processes.

Comment: assuming that it is a windows server, try this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc770556(v=ws.11)